# how calculate a egg's volume easy way?

Tags: geometry

I would like to show for some students from high school, how calculate a egg's volume from a easy way, I thought in use  Archimedes principle, but I don't now if this is the better way.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Looking at the answer, I am not certain that this is a mathematical question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The mathematical part is indeed only the derivation $V=A\cdot \Delta H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a prismatic container and fill partially with water (in such way we can fully submerge the egg without loosing water), then measure the difference of the water level after the egg has been submerged inside the container. From here we can determine the volume from the area of the container $A$ and the difference in height for the water level that is

$$V=A\cdot \Delta H$$

Refer to:

- https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/a.j.p.heck/research/eggmath/Measurements.html
- [Eureka (word)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_(word))

[image]

Comment: Better after the correction !

Comment: Why "prismatic"?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I've some problem with the language! :)

Comment: @smcc Because is simpler if we wan measure the difference in the level.

Comment: What is a "prismatic bowl"? (Perhaps this a translation issue.)

Comment: @smcc Maybe prismatic container is more appropriate?

Comment: @smcc, I think gimusi has https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry) in mind.

Comment: Do you mean "measuring jug"?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I thought similar way, but I had some doubt if this method really works, now I got my answer.

Comment: @TonyK Measuring jug is an optional!

Comment: @BarryCipra Exactly that, how can express that in a proper way?

Comment: @gimusi, I think what you want is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduated_cylinder

Comment: @BarryCipra Not exactly, I'm referring to a cylindrical container, not necessarly graduated.

Comment: @gimusi, well, you need some way to measure the volume, Your pictures show graduations.

Comment: @BarryCipra Without a graduated cylinder we can use a simple rule. Of course it is simpler to proceed with a graduated cylinder. The idea behind is the same.

Comment: @gimusi, you can measure your $\Delta H$ with a ruler. But how do you measure the cross-sectional area $A$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes it need to be as a given. Otherwise we can fill the container with water and by the weight obtain the datum.

Answer (score 2):

Just a variant on gimusi's answer: Take two kitchen measuring cups. Fill one with $250$ml of water. Place an egg in the other. Pour water over the egg until the second cup is filled to the $250$ml level. Measure what's left in the first.

Even better, if you have a pair of one-liter measuring cups: Put as many eggs as will fit below the liter line of one cup, then pour in water from the other. Measure what's left in the other, then divide by the number of eggs. This provides a side lesson on error analysis. (Also, I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out what to do if you only have one one-liter measuring cup and one $250$ml measuring cup.)

Finally, if your measuring cups are in fluid ounces instead of milliliters, and/or you want an answer in cubic inches, you'll have to do the appropriate conversions.